# How can I turn off the auto highlight "found" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, replace, highlighting

I have a huge XML file to be edited in Visual Studio. When I carry out a regular expression FIND search, VS does a search after every key stroke on the search panel which makes the application so slow. How can I disable auto highlighting feature?